# Having a form under a For-Each cycle in Thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am new in Spring Boot and I have a problem with Thymeleaf. I want to use an HTML form under a For Each cycle, but I get an exception.

This is my code:

```
<tr th:each="item : ${users}">
    <td th:text="${item.getFirstName()}">First Name</td>
    <td th:text="${item.getLastName()}">Last Name</td>
    <td th:text="${item.getEmailAddress()}">Email Address</td>
    <td th:text="${item.getDateOfBirth()}">Date of Birth</td>
    <!--<td><a th:href="${'/user/edit/' + user.id}">Edit</a></td> -->
    <td>Edit</td>
    <td>
        <form th:object="${item}" th:action="@{/delete}" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" th:field="*{firstName}"/>
            <input type="hidden" th:field="*{lastName}"/>
            <input type="hidden" th:field="*{emailAddress}"/>
            <input type="hidden" th:field="*{dateOfBirth}"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Delete"/>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And this is the exception I get:

```
[THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Exception processing template "users": Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor' (users:31)
```

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use thymeleaf as view engine in my spring boot app.Following example code might be help you get some idea about it.

**User model**

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id", nullable = false )
    private Long id; 

    @Column(name="user_name" )
    private String userName;


    @Email(message="Email not valid")
    @Column(name="email",nullable=false)
    private String email;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

}
```

User controller

```
model.addAttribute("users", userService.getAllusers());
```

User view

```
<tr th:each="user : ${users}">
    <td th:text="${user.id}"></td>
    <td th:text="${user.email}"></td>
    <td th:text="${user.userName}"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. I solved my problem adding id to each user account and then it was not necessary to pass a full object via POST query.